# Python - iterate over rows and columns

Tags: python, compare, iteration, rows, calculated-columns

First of all, please pardon my skills. I am trying to get into Python, I learn just for fun, let's say, I don't use it professionally and I am quite bad, to be honest. Probably there will be basic errors on my question.

Anyway, I am trying to go over a dataframe's rows and columns. I want to check if the values of the columns (except the first one) are NaNs. If they are, then they should change to the value of the first one.

```
import math

for index, row in rawdata3.iterrows():
    test = row[0]
    for column in row:
        if math.isnan(row.loc[column]) == True:
            row.loc[column] = test
```

The error I get is something like this:

> the label [4.0] is not in the [columns]

I also had other errors with slightly different code like:

> cannot do label indexing on class pandas.core.indexes.base.Index with these indexers class float

Could you give me a hand, please?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Comment: Can you post you DataFrame? Have you tried to use DataFrame.isna()?

Comment: Something like this:
A B C
5 NaN 2
6 5 NaN
9 NaN NaN
2 4 6

And it should look like this:
A B C
5 5 2
6 5 6
9 9 9
2 4 6

(if NaN, then replace by value of first column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way but this works fine:

```
for i in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[i].isnull(), i] = df.loc[df[i].isnull(), 'A']
```

output:

```
   A    B    C
0  5  5.0  2.0
1  6  5.0  6.0
2  9  9.0  9.0
3  2  4.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Where df is:

```
   A    B    C
0  5  NaN  2.0
1  6  5.0  NaN
2  9  NaN  NaN
3  2  4.0  6.0
```

Use `transpose` and `fillna`:

> Due to fillna "NotImplementedEerror"
>   NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column
>   by column
>   `df.fillna(value=df.A, axis=1)` will not work. Therefore we use:

```
df.T.fillna(df.A).T
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  5.0  5.0  2.0
1  6.0  5.0  6.0
2  9.0  9.0  9.0
3  2.0  4.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but, by row, the values of NaN should be replaced by the value on the first column, not on the previous one.
For example, C1 should be 6 and not 5.
Cheers.

Comment: @SamuelValente Here's another option.